# GPU can't switch to higher resolutions

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, gpu

My PC system seems to boot just fine, however, directly after the Windows circle has finished and it should switch the resolution and then show the login screen it turns black, takes a few seconds, then my monitor also registers that no signal is coming anymore and goes into stand by. My system waits for about a minute and then restarts and goes to the Windows-oops-something-happened-restore/etc.-options. I already tried most of the options and booting into Safe Mode works just fine.

My buest guess is that my GPU is broken and can't switch into high resolution anymore.

1) Is there a way to validate this guess? Can I somehow load the driver while in safe mode and try to go into a higher resolution?

2) If that's the case, my CPU (a Intel Core i7 2600K) should also have an on-chip GPU, however, my motherboard doesn't seem to feature some HDI/VGA/HDMI/whatever slot. Am I right that I can't use this on-board GPU in any way, or is there a way to tunnel the signal through the dedicated GPU?w

Comment: In safe mode I deactivated my GPU device in the device manager which allowed me to boot back into the system. Now is the question how to further diagnose the problem...any ideas?

Comment: (1) You can try to boot ubuntu installer disk and select "try without installation", then normally it will set the resolution to the native even 4K. (2) Windows 10 can do that, GPU and display pipe is decoupled, you can use iGPU and output it through the eGPU's port. Why don't you just try that? Disable the eGPU and enable the iGPU in Device Manager.

Comment: How to do (2) ? I don't see an iGPU entry in the device manager's list. Do I have to install some drivers first? My CPU, according to official specs, does have an onchip GPU.

Comment: It looks like there aren't any drivers available at https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/52214/Intel-Core-i7-2600K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3-80-GHz-   -  is this really true? Unfortunately not even the Windows 8 drivers can be installed ... don't know why though, because it's a different OS or because somehow my system is otherwise not compatible? Maybe because of some BIOS setting? I've got an ASUS Pro board from 2011.

Comment: My BIOS doesn't seem to have any option regarding such a setting...would really appreciate any help.

Comment: It is not in BIOS, it is in Windows 10 Device Manager. In BIOS you only need to be sure both are enabled or Win10 may not see them at all.

Comment: In the device manager I see only one graphics adapter (the dedicated GPU) which I have to disable in order to be able to boot without safe mode. How to add the integrated card to the device manager?

Comment: They should both be under "Display Adaptor" root node. You can try other browse mode and find each node again. You have to be sure it is not disabled by BIOS. There could be another bad news reason - your BIOS disables iGPU by default and you cannot use it at all since the mother board is designed for CPU without iGPU. Even more the board may does not route the trace that send display signal from CPU to PCH at all - which is called Intel Flexible Display Interface .

Comment: What brand and model is your GPU?

Comment: ASUS Nvidia GTX 580